# Main monitor returning the sum of the resolutions with java

Tags: java, graphics, monitor

Well, Im working with the LibGDX framework for a project and I need to get the resolution of the monitors in the user, for this, im using this from AWT

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
```

To get the devices then getting the height and width of each one.
I've 2 monitors, my main one, that is 1080x1920 and the secondary 768x1366
The problem is that im getting as return this

```
Device 1 Height: 1080
Device 1 Width: 3286
Device 2 Height: 768
Device 2 Width: 1366
```

Why are this getting the sum of the 2 resolutions in the main one?

I'm running this in Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon

Comment: I'm not familiar with LibGDX, but these look suspiciously like AWT calls.  Edit: LibGDX's documentation mentions that it uses Scene2D / Scene2D.ui, so you might want to see if it has APIs for getting the screen width.

Comment: yes, they are from AWT, im using this to make some implementations in other components. Question edited.